# Log in to PC after WOL is sent

Tags: c#, android, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to write an app for android that will wake up my computer from its sleep state.  I've found many posts on how to do that and am confident that piece of my code will work.

My question is after the computer wakes up, I have it set to require a username/password in order to get in.  Is it possible to send a packet from my application to the PC in order to log in to the computer?  I've done some Googling on this part of the issue but haven't come across anything yet.

The end goal is to be able to use my android application to automate some things on my PC without have to be at the PC.  There will be a c# application running on my PC which the android app talks to in order to accomplish this task.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to log in? Any server software would run without needing a log in first.

Comment: This is actually going to run an application on my personal machine to automate some things that will need access to the desktop.  I shouldn't have used server I suppose.

Comment: Yes it would be possible to do, but I think you would need a server / windows service to intercept the packet and react. I think you maybe should expand your question then to what the end result would be. Maybe then people will be able to suggest what you can do.

Comment: Good idea, just added a little more information to explain what I'm trying to do.  The service is a good idea that may be the way I need to go to make this work.

Comment: It all depends on what kind of security you also require to make it safe for being exposed the the outside world. Something like OWIN is easy to implement and combined as a windows service should do what you need. http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana  http://www.docstorus.com/viewer.aspx?code=7c7ccc28-6503-4779-877e-f350faab6741